# Use WAL files for PostgreSQL record version control?

Tags: postgresql, version-control

I want to be able to track changes to records in a PostgreSQL database. I've considered using a version field and on-update rules or triggers such that previous versions of records are kept in the table (or in a separate table). This would have the advantage of making it possible to view the version history of a record with a simple select statement. However, this functionality is something I think likely to be seldom used.

How could I satisfy the requirement of being able to construct a "version history" for a record using the WAL files? Reading the WAL and Point-in-Time recovery documentation at PostgreSQL.org has helped me understand how the state of the entire database can be rolled back to an arbitrary point in time, but not how to deal with update mistakes in particular records.

Comment: My opinion of your WAL approach while interesting seems overly complex at best. Why not do it the way everyone else does it and use a trigger or rule to capture change.  It's straightforward and isn't some dream state idea.

Comment: Just a clarification: One cannot roll back the database to an arbitrary point in time.  You can only go forward from a known consistent base point to a single future point in time.  The end result looks like the database rolled back, but your description implies that you can simply tell it to rewind back to some point in time and that's just not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot do this at this time.  There is a large effort underway on the postgresql-hackers mailing list (the dev list) to rework WAL and build an interface to allow for logical replication in (possibly) PostgreSQL 9.3.

This is basically what you appear to be trying to do and, based on the discussions on that list, it is definitely not a trivial task.